# Check a checkbox based on list value using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have check box in the form with the following values:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin1" />Admin1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin2" />Admin2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin3" />Admin3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin4" />Admin4<br />
```

I have a Roles List that is coming from the server side with the values :

```
Roles
{
Admin1
Admin4
}
```

Now based on the Roles value the options `Admin1` and `Admin4` will be checked in the check box. How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: How is the data being returned from the server? Please post the actual value instead of a pseudocode array.

Comment: The data is coming from a asp.net side. The Roles object is a string array looking like : { [0] = "Admin1" , [1] = "Admin4" }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[value="Admin3"]').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: I think I have to use a each loop on the client side . You cannot hard code like : $('input[value="Admin3"]').prop("checked", true);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe This can help You :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var peran = new Array("Admin1", "Admin4");
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $(".ceks").each(function(){
                var attrib = $(this).attr("value");
                for(var x=0; x<peran.length; x++){
                    if( peran[x] == attrib ){
                        $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                    }
                }
              });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin1" class="ceks" />Admin1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin2" class="ceks" />Admin2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin3" class="ceks" />Admin3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin4" class="ceks" />Admin4<br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes thanks.. Though I saw your post late but this is the way I did it .

Answer (score 0):

If the page is an asp.net page then why not just set the checkboxes in the code behind?

```
IF (criteria is met)
    (checkboxID).selected = true
end if
```